# What is the best way to fit multivariate linear equation?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to fit the linear equation of the form Y=coff1*A+coff2*B+C and calculate constant values coff1, coff2, and C. I did several ways but I got a huge difference in coefficient values. What is the efficient way to fit this type of equation?

```
import pandas as pd
import lmfit
dataset = {'A': [0.021426, -0.003970,0.001040, -0.003789, 0.009423, 0.046421, 0.039426, 0.027010, 0.024423, 0.022277],
        'B': [ 0.000056, 0.000098, 0.000057, 0.000066, 0.000047 ,-0.009798,-0.008069,-0.005124,-0.004505,-0.004006],
        'y': [242245.852, 153763.713, 205788.950, 161561.380, 250021.084,235739.216, 283089.372, 429715.097, 480362.889, 531978.557]}
data = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
A=data['A']
B=data['B']
y=data['y']



def resid(params,A, B, ydata):
    f_rot = params['f_rot'].value
    xip = params['xip'].value
    xim = params['xim'].value
    
    
    f_obs =f_rot+A*xip-B*xim 
    return f_obs - ydata

#data = np.loadtxt("C:/Users/USER/Desktop/Combined_values_FINAL_EAP.txt")
params = lmfit.Parameters()
params.add('f_rot',    15)
params.add('xip',  2)
params.add('xim',      10)

fit =lmfit.minimize(resid, params, args=(y,A,B), method='least_squares')
lmfit.report_fit(fit)
#Answer of this fit
#f_rot:  3.9748e-04 +/- 0.00139658 (351.36%) (init = 150000)
 #   xip:    3.7470e-10 +/- 4.7904e-09 (1278.48%) (init = 2)
  #  xim:    0.19744062 +/- 0.03694633 (18.71%) (init = 10)
```